# SPARQL using union with a dataset

Tags: union, sparql, option-type

The challenge set is to use the UNION keyword with the following datasets and return a list of grandads.

RELDB1 holds 2 useful tables:

The fatherOf table has this data:

```
Table fatherof:
('Chuck', 'Paul'),
('Chuck', 'Bonnie'),
('Jerry', 'George'),
('Jerry', 'Mary'),
('Chuck', 'Olivia'),
('Paul', 'Joan'),
('George', 'John'),
('George', 'Carole'),
('Ringo', 'Yoko'),
('Ringo', 'Peter')
```

and the table Person has:

```
Table person:
('Sara', 64, 'f'),
('Nancy', 68, 'f'),
('Mary', 27, 'f'),
('Olivia', 37, 'f'),
('Bonnie', 35, 'f'),
('Carole', 7, 'f'),
('Yoko', 6, 'f'),
('Joan', 9, 'f'),
('Chuck', 67, 'm'),
('Jerry', 65, 'm'),
('Paul', 30, 'm'),
('George', 25, 'm'),
('Ringo', 39, 'm'),
('John', 8, 'm'),
('Peter', 11, 'm')
```

I tried this query:

```
>SELECT ?x ?y ?z  
>WHERE {{?x rdf:type ex:Person}  
>UNION  
>{?x ex:fatherOf ?y . ?y ex:fatherOf ?z}}  
>ORDER BY (?x)
```

The output was everyone in the Person table and then also the son and grandchild for Chuck (Paul, Joan) and Jerry (George, John and George and Carole). I tried removing ?y ?z. The query returned a list of the person table!

How can I modify the query so that the UNION remains but I get only grandparents. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use union.  Why not just a pattern like `?grandfather fatherOf ?father . ?father fatherOf ?child .` or even, with a property path,  `?grandfather fatherOf/fatherOf ?child`.

Comment: "I haven't tried a query yet." Why not? Trying some sample queries would be quicker than writing up a stack overflow question, especially since we don't have any way to run a query on data that you haven't provided to us.

Comment: This sounds like some homework or exercises, so it would be good if you try some queries first by yourself.

Comment: I seem to have annoyed people :(. That wasn't my intention. I have put in the data: table - person and table - fatherOf. I didn't design the databases. I'm learning to use SPARQL (with Protégé). I can't get things to display properly on here:

Comment: @ Joshua Taylor @ AKSW Thanks for replying. I seem to have annoyed people :(. That wasn't my intention. I have put in the data: table - person and table - fatherOf. I didn't design the databases. I'm learning to use SPARQL (with Protégé) for work and I'm up at 11pm trying to get my head around it. I can't get things to display properly on here. Using my logic a suitable query might look like:    >select ?x where > ?x ex:fatherOf ?y  . ?y ex: fatherOf ?z

Comment: SELECT distinct ?x ?y ?z
WHERE { ?x ex:fatherOf ?y . ?y ex:fatherOf ?z} ORDER BY (?x)    Returns 3 rows of data

Comment: @nidgy, instead of posting these things in comments (which have very limited formatting capabilities), please [edit] your question to make the question more clear. If you need help using SO's formatting, see [help/formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Jeen - thank you for the links to the formatting pages. And thanks for improving my question.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra. How do I make sure the edited version appears? The neat columns look like rows again.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return every person who is a grandfather. In your question you show that you are only returning ***paternal grandparents***...

A grandfather has children who has children who has children.

```
                                        Grandfather
                              Son                    Daughter
                        Son       Daughter       Son        Daughter
```

The union part come into play because you are going to return the following:

1. ?z father of ?a
2. ?a mother of ?b
3. ?a father of ?b

   ```
                                             ?z
                                   ?a                ?a
                              ?b        ?b       ?b       ?b
   ```

You need a union on the mother and father of ?b as you are combining the results of multiple triple patterns. I won't provide you with the query for this as this is classwork, however, this should help you arrive at the answer using what you have.